# Вывод выборки SQL скрипта в файл .csv через PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Суть: необходимо сделать ежеквартальное подключение к БД и делать выгрузку определенных таблиц с записью в файл и последующей отправкой на почту.
Решил реализовать эту задачу посредством PS (пока только с формированием выгрузки и записью в файл).

Есть скрипт.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=0.0.0.0\SQL2008,1234;Initial Catalog=SYST;User Id=adm; Password=pass;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT    table_1.field_1, table_1.field_2, table_2.field_1, table_2.field_2,
                          FROM         table_1.field_2, INNER JOIN
                      table_1.field_2 ON table_1.field_2 = table_2.field_1"
$result = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
write-output $result.getname(0) $result.getname(1) $result.getname(2) $result.getname(3)  >> C:\test.csv
while ($result.Read())
{write-output $result.Getvalue(0) $result.GetValue(1) $result.GetValue(2) $result.GetValue(3) >> C:\aaa.csv}
$SqlConnection.close()|  Out-Host
```

Он записывает результат в файл aaa.csv списком. Вопрос: 
1) как можно сформировать таблицу со столбцами table_1 и table_2? format-table начинает выводить какую-то чушь.
2) и оптимально ли выбрано решение для поставленной задачи?

Заранее извиняюсь. PS только начинаю изучать, так что возможно задаю глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, позвольте начать с того, что у вас опечатки в описании при использовании названий таблиц. Подозреваю, что вы всё же а) join'ите table1 с table 2 а не их колонки; б) В итоговой таблице хотите иметь названия колонок, а не таблиц.

Дальше, вы формируете csv вручную, это не практично, поскольку есть cmdlet `Export-CSV` & `ConvertTo-Csv`. Для того чтобы их использовать, вам нужен набор однотипных объектов, проперти которых и будут колонками. Исходные данные у вас в виде таблицы, и как данные так и названия колонок нужно вытягивать вручную, поэтому эти объекты для экспорта придётся создавать тоже вручную. Для того чтобы создать подобные объекты, можно ыоспользоваться `Select-Object`. Вот *пример* как это сделать с environment variables:

```
$x=@{}
$collection = @()
gci Env: | ForEach-Object {
    $x.Prop=$_.Name
    $x.Content=$_.Value
    $x.Random=(Get-Random -Maximum 2000)
    $collection += New-Object psobject -Property $x
}
```

После этого, наш `$collection` можно как сохранить в CSV

```
$collection | Export-Csv text.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

так и например, вывести таблицей на экран

```
$collection | Format-Table -Property Prop,Random,Content
```

То есть ваш цикл вычитки из базы можно переписать вот так

```
while ($result.Read()) {
    for($i=0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
        $x[$result.GetName($i)]=$result.GetValue($i)
    }
    $collection += New-Object psobject -Property $x #В принципе, если данные в память не влезают, можно сразу и экспортировать здесь через Export-Csv -Append
}
```

Ну а после этого уже выводить - через `Format-Table` на экран/консоль и через `Export-Csv` в файл. Можно ещё через `Convert-Csv` в строку всё запихнуть, а потом её куда-нибудь использовать.

P.S.: Вместо `Close()` я бы их всё-таки `Dispose()`ил. Правда, в PSh это скорее дело вкуса.